# Search for matching LI items in separate UL

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to figure out how to find 'li' items with matching text that are in two different 'ul's when the user clicks a button so that they can all be removed. The button is appended to each 'li' and I can successfully get the text from it and remove the original item. The 'li' are sortable and the user can add more, so this can't be done with the locations of the 'li's.

Right now I have this (I've removed some things to make it more understandable):

Javascript:

```
$("li")
    .prepend("<span class='ui-icon'></span>")    

$(".ui-icon")
    .click(function() {
        var itemText = $(this).closest("li").text();

        $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        }); 

        $("li:contains(itemText)").remove(); //the part I'm having trouble with 
    })
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="items">
    <li>
        <h3 id="title">Title1</h3>
        <p id="body">Body1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 id="title">Title2</h3>
        <p id="body">Body2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 id="title">Title3</h3>
        <p id="body">Body3</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 id="title">Title4</h3>
        <p id="body">Body4</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="favs">
    <li>
        <h3 id="title">Title2</h3>
        <p id="body">Body2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 id="title">Title3</h3>
        <p id="body">Body3</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 id="title">Title1</h3>
        <p id="body">Body1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3 id="title">Title4</h3>
        <p id="body">Body4</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what does "this is the part I'm having trouble with" mean? What trouble? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: just to notice: you have multiple `<p>` elements with the same ID, although an ID should be unique. You should use `class='body'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".ui-icon")
    .click(function() {
        var item = item.closest("li");
        var itemText = item.text();
        var parentUL = item.closest("ul");

        item.fadeOut(200, function() {
            item.remove();
        }); 

        parentUL.siblings('ul').find("li:contains(" + itemText + ")").remove(); //the part I'm having trouble with 
    })
```

I think this is what you're looking for. This makes sure that any except the one you're fading out are removed.

As an aside, `id`s should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this line:

```
$("li:contains(itemText)").remove()
```

should be:

```
$("li:contains(" + itemText + ")").remove()
```

jQuery selctors have no context about the variables in your scope.  Selectors are string, so you need to build a string from your itemText variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for `li` elements that contain the string 'itemText' and not the value of the itemText variable.

Change

```
 $("li:contains(itemText)").remove();
```

to

```
 $("li:contains(" + itemText + ")").remove();
```